# Criar o arquivo .txt em PYTHON caso ele não exista

Tags: python, python-3.x, txt

O codigo:

```
        arquivo = open(input('Nome do arquivo a ser editado:'), 'r')
        texto = arquivo.readlines()
        texto.append(input('Insira o texto:'))
        arquivo = open(input('Nome do arquivo a ser editado:'), 'w')
        arquivo.writelines(texto)
        arquivo.close()
```

Ele lé um arquivo .TXT já existente grava oque esta escrito dentro dele.
E soma o texto que for inserido, eu encontrei essa forma de fazer que requer que ele peça 2x o nome do arquivo.
Existe alguma forma que não precise chamar 2x o pedido do nome ?

```
        File "C:\Users\Americo\Desktop\TESTE\Trabson.py", line 51, in sys_calls
        arquivo = open(input('Nome do arquivo a ser editado:'), 'r')
        FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'teste.txt'
```

E alem disso se o arquivo não existir, como eu faço para criar e colocar o texto que eu desejo dentro avisando que o arquivo foi criado e que não existia.
Um outro usuário havia colocado em outra duvida o seguinte trecho de codigo:

```
      if os.path.isfile(diretorio):
      ...
      ficheiro = open(diretorio, "w") # criamos/abrimos o ficheiro
      #.... .... ... operacoes no ficheiro
      ficheiro.close()
```

Isso e aplicado neste caso para a confirmação do arquivo txt ?
O trecho funcionou para parte do meu codigo serviu para toda a parte de MOVER CRIAR DELETAR E RENOMEAR algum arquivo ou diretorio.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Se fizer assim não precisa chamar 2 vezes.

```
arquivo = open(input('Nome do arquivo a ser editado:'), 'r+')
texto = arquivo.readlines()
texto.append(input('insira o valor'))
arquivo.writelines(texto)
arquivo.close()
```

Agora, caso o arquivo informado não exista pode ser assim.

```
try:
    nome_arquivo = input('Nome do arquivo a ser editado:')
    arquivo = open(nome_arquivo, 'r+')
except FileNotFoundError:
    arquivo = open(nome_arquivo, 'w+')
    arquivo.writelines(u'Arquivo criado pois nao existia')
#faca o que quiser
arquivo.close()
```

Comment: Era essa exceção que eu não sabia como fazer,consegui terminar essa parte do exercício, eu não consegui achar muito sobre pela internet essa materia entra dentro de SO e meu professor nao quiz me ajudar, oque causou bastante confusão pra eu conseguir terminar ;/
Mas obrigado consegui resolver o problema!

Answer (score 2):

Talvez você pode usar o "append" de arquivos para resolver esse problema. Mas, fazendo o mínimo de alteração em teu código, voce poderia colocar o input em uma variável, ou seja:

```
    nome_do_arquivo = input('Nome do arquivo a ser editado:')
    arquivo = open(nome_do_arquivo, 'r')
    texto = arquivo.readlines()
    texto.append(input('Insira o texto:'))
    arquivo = open(nome_do_arquivo, 'w')
    arquivo.writelines(texto)
    arquivo.close()
```

Ou você pode fazer o seguinte código:

```
    arquivo = open(input('Nome do arquivo a ser editado:'), 'r+')
    print(arquivo.readlines()) #Consegue ler
    arquivo.write(input('Insira o texto:')+"\n") #consegue editar
    arquivo.close()
```

É importante lembrar que o arquivo deve existir, caso contrario verifique antes e crie.

Comment: Obrigado por o raciocino nesse trecho não usarei isso mas ele vai servir pro próximo problema agradecido pela ajuda obrigado pelo tempo gasto!